# What is the quickest way to stop nuclear fusion without removing the fuel?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

Would dumping enormous amounts of liquid nitrogen cool it quickly thus extinguishing it? Could a bomb disperse the fuel preventing fusion? Could adding a material stop the fuel from fusing? Is there another method?

Comment: Under what conditions?

Comment: I'm not super savvy on the Navier-Stokes and other magnetohydrodynamics, but I would imagine turning off the confinement field would do this relatively quickly whether it's magnetic or laser based, or in a muon catalyzed case, quit feeding the fuel muons. If it's gravitationally confined like the sun, you might have problems.

Comment: Did you actually mean to ask about stopping a fission reaction, like the runaway reactor failures at Chernobyl or Fukushima? If so, since you already have an answer about fusion, you should ask a follow-up question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sustain fusion, tremendous pressures and temperatures are required. all you need to do to almost instantly stop a fusion reactor is to release the pressure on the plasma/fuel mix.

Comment: Fusion is not a chain reaction: it is enough to stop the injection of deuterium or tritium fuel for the reaction to stop.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, could a magnetic force, combined with a depressurization zone prevent detonation of nuclear bomb before fusion?  Would be a two step shield but you would need to cross both steps before a target could be reached, thus making bombs such as SATIN undetonated on impacted.  Speed, no longer becomes a factor.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/395453)